# Getting 400 in GraphQL while mutation request in React Js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

Here is What I tried
I took variable `activityid` and `memberid`.

```
  const EnrollActivityMutation = gql`
        mutation ($activityid: String!, $memberid: String!) {
            createActivityEnrollment(
                data: {
                    activity: { connect: { id: $activityid } }
                    member: { connect: { id: $memberid } }
                }
            ) {
                member {
                    name
                }
                id
                activity {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    `;
```

```
  const [createActivityEnrollment, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(
        EnrollActivityMutation
    );
```

```
  createActivityEnrollment({
            variables: {
                activityid,
                memberid
            }
        })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I am getting error of `400 Bad Request`
`http://localhost:3000/api/graphql 400 (Bad Request)`

I am not sure if there is problem regarding variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const EnrollActivityMutation = gql`
        mutation ($activityid: ID!, $memberid: ID!) {
            createActivityEnrollment(
                data: {
                    activity: { connect: { id: $activityid } }
                    member: { connect: { id: $memberid } }
                }
            ) {
                member {
                    name
                }
                id
                activity {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    `;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).